# PHP magic_quotes_gpc = off but slashes are still added

Tags: php

magic_quotes_gpc has been set to off and confirmed by phpinfo(), but content is still inserted into the database with slashes

Note: I'm using mysql_real_escape_string() to insert each value, I have tested this function to see if it's causing any issues but it made no changes to the value inserted into the database

PHP Version 5.2.12
MySQL Client API version 5.0.91

Comment: This belongs to stackoverflow.com; could you add the affected PHP code?

Comment: Also, it's not an answer to your question, but you *might* want to take a look at PDO to avoid escaping stuff.

Answer (score 1):

magic_quotes_**gpc** applies to **G**ET, **P**OST and **C**ookies only. There is another setting which influence the addition of slashes. The list can be found at [PHP: Runtime Configuration#magic-quotes-runtime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-runtime), it includes mysql_fetch_* functions.

Make sure you do not apply mysql_real_escape_string twice.

Comment: I'm having this same problem, but all magic_quote_* related settings are off (confirmed by phpinfo()).

Comment: Could it be a PHP extension or part of your script adding the slashes?

Comment: I actually ended up figuring it out. Here's my question on the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990734/quotes-being-escaped-when-magic-quotes-gpc-is-set-to-off/